# URL appears to be pointing to a pre-production environment in App Studio

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-appstudio

I'm using App Studio in Microsoft teams in order to deploy a web app hosted in an URL, under the manifest editor, I've created an app.

After setting all the requested information, I am getting those warnings:

[image]

Also, when I'm trying to click on install button it says that I'm not authorized to add the app to this team.

Answer (score 0):

The warnings are just that, warnings. They won't prevent you from installing your app by package or adding to your Line of Business store.

It sounds like you don't have permissions to install the app into that team, or installing apps is disabled by your tenant admin. You'll need to check and make sure your tenant is configured correctly.

The settings you'll need at the tenant level are:

- Org-wide custom app setting => Allow interaction with custom apps => On — This setting enables or disables custom apps for your organization. It needs to be on.
- Team custom app setting => Allow members to upload custom apps => On/Off — This setting applies to each individual team inside Microsoft Teams. If you want to install your app for a specific team, this will need to be on for that team.
- User custom app policy => User can upload custom apps => On/Off — This setting controls the permissions for an individual user. You'll need to enable this for individuals that are allowed to upload custom apps.

And then you'll also need to have permissions to install to the team you're trying to install to.

For more information, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/prepare-your-o365-tenant#enable-custom-teams-apps-and-turn-on-custom-app-uploading

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, actually I'm deploying the app in my local teams instance

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "local"? Teams is always tied to an O365 tenant - you must configure that tenant correctly before you can install apps.